# Read and write to a list of names and scores - python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that gives the user a short quiz and create a score, which I have done, then I would like to add them to a list in a .txt file. In the program I will ask them their name, so say I have a list such as this;

Bob,7

Bill,5

Jane,6

and someone takes the quiz and inputs the name Bob and gets a score 4 the list will update to;

Bob,4

Bill,5

Jane,6

or someone new takes a quiz, Sarah it will change to;

Bob,4

Bill,5

Jane,6

Sarah,7

So far I have;

```
import random
file = open("scores.txt", "r")

UserScore=random.randint(0,10)

lines = file.readlines()

file.close()

student=input('What is your name? ')

file = open("scores.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    name, score = line.strip().split(",")
    if name!=student:
        file.write(line)
    else:
        file.write(name +',' +str(UserScore))
```

I've randomised the score for now to make it easier to read, however that will be from what the user answered correctly, and I thought this code would read the file then check each name from each line and if the name they entered is the same to the name in the list the line will be replaced with the name and score. However, the file just ends up blank, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters have you considered using a dictionary?

Comment: Most likely the file is blank because `lines` is blank

Comment: I can't use a dictionary for this, even though I know it would make things easier, but lines isn't blank.

Comment: is this exactly how you open the files? I would also write the code more like http://pastebin.com/cPjb2LjG

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think is a better idea using the Python pickle module:

In [1]: import pickle

In [2]: scores={'Bob':75, 'Angie':60, 'Anita':80}         #create a dict called scores

In [3]: pickle.dump(scores,open('scores.dat','wb'))       #dump the pickled object into the file

In [4]: !ls scores.dat                                    #verify that the file has been created
scores.dat

In [5]: !cat scores.dat  #list out the file
(dp0
S'Bob'
p1
I75
sS'Angie'
p2
I60
sS'Anita'
p3
I80
s.

In [9]: tscores = pickle.load(open('scores.dat','rb')) #Verification: load the pickled object from the file into a new dict

In [10]: tscores  #Verification: list out the new dict
Out[10]: {'Angie': 60, 'Anita': 80, 'Bob': 75}

In [11]: scores == tscores  #Verify that the dict object is equivalent to the newly created dict object
Out[11]: True

Comment: I quote *I can't use a dictionary for this*

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code and the first time you run it, then you *rewrite* the file in one single line. So the next time you run the script on this single line file, you get an unpack exception in the split function and hence you write nothing to the file, resulting in an empty file.

A solution could be to add the newline char again when writing the lines to the file.

```
import random
file = open("scores.txt", "r")

UserScore=random.randint(0,10)

lines = file.readlines()

file.close()

student=input('What is your name? ')

file = open("scores.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    name, score = line.strip().split(",")
    if name!=student:
        file.write(line + '\n')
    else:
        file.write(name +',' +str(UserScore) + '\n')
```

Comment: This will not add the new person.

Comment: @user2097159 I was trying to solve the issue the OP has so far about ending up with an empty file. Not giving him a solution for the program the OP is trying to solve by herself.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you elaborate a little bit? I don't see why not. Adding the newline again is trying to fix the stripped one to avoid having a line with more than one comma. Maybe a code reorganization would have been helpful, but my intention was just trying to give the OP an explanation of why of the empty file.

Comment: because the code would not run at all if the data was all on one line because  `name, score = line.strip().split(",")` would throw an error, the OP's problem is apparently the file ends up blank initially so the actual problem is from something that the OP has not provided

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Exactly. And that error is what can cause the empty (truncated) file because of the `open("scores.txt", "w")` and no writes because of the unpack error. But, maybe you are right and the file is empty before it is even read for the first time.

Comment: yep but there does not seem to be an error so there is something else happening but impossible to tell without seeing the actual code

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you want

```
import random
file = open("scores.txt", "r")

UserScore=random.randint(0,10)

lines = file.readlines()

file.close()

student=input('What is your name? ')
flag = True
file = open("scores.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    name, score = line.strip().split(",")
    if name!=student:
        file.write(line + '\n')
    else:
        file.write(name +',' +str(UserScore) + '\n')
        flag = False
if flag:
    file.write(student +',' +str(UserScore) + '\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

I adjusted a bit of your code and took the liberty to remove the random part and name, score part. But I got some working code. I assume you can make it work for your situation.

```
file = open("scores.txt", "r+")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
us = 15

student = input('What is your name? ')

ls = []
file = open("scores.txt", "r+")
found_student = False

for line in lines:

    line = line.strip()
    ls = line.split(",")
    print("Parsing: " + str(ls))

    if not line:
        print("Empty line")
        pass
    elif ls[0] != student:
        file.write(line + "\n")
    else:
        found_student = True
        file.write(ls[0] + ',' + str(us) + "\n")

if not found_student:
    file.write(student + ',' + str(us) + "\n" )

file.close()
```